# Passing parameters/Objects between threads

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

I am working on a multi threaded application and ran into a problem with passing parameters between threads.

```
Private Students as Students
Private ListOfStudents as List(Of Students.Student)
Public Sub AddStudents()
                Dim AddThread As New Thread(AddressOf Add)
                AddThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
                AddThread.Start(Param)
End Sub

Private Sub Add(Byval Param as String)
Students = new Students(Param) 'Add Students to List
ListOfStudents = Students.GetStudents() 'Returns List of Students
For Each S in ListOfStudents
Dim L As New ListViewItem(S.Name)
        L.SubItems.Add(S.Marks)    
ListView1.Items.Add(L)    
Next
End Sub
```

This works fine.
Now..

```
Public Sub GetStudentInfo()
For Each S in ListOfStudents
Dim SubThread As New Thread(AddressOf CheckStudent)
            SubThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
            SubThread.IsBackground = True
            SubThread.Start(S)
Next
End Sub
Private Result as String
Private Sub CheckStudent(Byval S as Students.Student)
Result &= S.Name & ":" & S.Marks 
End Sub
```

Result is supposed to be Ravi:92 but it is always Nothing.
Result is null:null/Nothing:Nothing

Here is the Students class:

```
Public Class Students
Public Class Student
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Marks As String
End Class
Public Function GetStudents() As List(Of Student)
Dim N as New List(Of Student)
N = ''code
Return N
End Function
End Class
```

I've done some research and it maybe happening because the list is being modified on a separate thread(AddThread) ans is being called on another thread for retrieving list(SubThread).
What do I do?

Comment: Side question: Why are you creating another thread if you only make it an STA thread? If you want to perform proper multithreading you have to use an MTA thread and perform invocation to access UI elements. -- Here's how you can perform thread-safe invocation: [Performing thread-safe calls using Control.Invoke()](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201608201030367308722).

Comment: The code is incomplete, you don't show how you are reading the Result variable.  But it certainly *screams* threading race bug loudly, you **must** wait for the thread to complete before you can have an accurate value of Result.  When you use a thread and have to wait for it then you lose all benefits of threading.  Use the BackgroundWorker or Task classes to make it useful again, they allow running code after the thread completes.